# What is the systematic way to convert any arbitrary finite dimensional representation into block diagonal form?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Given any arbitrary representation, how do I convert it into block diagonal form, or find its irreducible representation?

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to know the characters of the irreducibe representations, a standard way is to couple them against the character of the given representations under the canonical pairing.